# SuperSlim doesn't work with Android support library 23.2.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, superslim

I tried implement SuperSlim with the last Android Support Library (23.2.1) but the recyclerView doesn't show the data, otherwise with the older library (23.2.0) works properly. Does anyone how to fix this problem??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that with the 23.4.0 support library and 0.4.13 super slim versions, it's working again.